# Expo linear gradient not accepting gradient start&end props

Tags: react-native, expo

I've implemented expo-linear-gradient on a new generated project, with expo TV ( https://github.com/expo/examples/tree/master/with-tv ).

The component works for default gradient ( No start & end props specified ), but once I specify those to change the direction of the gradient, the module fails to work

> ERROR  Cannot set prop 'startPoint' on view 'class expo.modules.lineargradient.LinearGradientView'
> → Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class declares 0 type parameters, but 2 were provided.

Here's my package file :

````
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@gorhom/portal": "^1.0.14",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.21.0",
    "@react-native-tvos/config-tv": "~0.0.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "@shopify/flash-list": "^1.6.3",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "bluebird": "^3.7.2",
    "expo": "^50.0.0-preview.4",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "12.5.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.26.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "^6.4.1",
    "moti": "^0.27.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "npm:react-native-tvos@~0.73.1-0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.6.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.7.4",
    "react-native-svg": "^14.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "typescript": "^5.3.0"
  },
  "expo": {
    "install": {
      "exclude": [
        "react-native"
      ]
    }
  },
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  }
}
```
````

Comment: Expo sdk 50 is still in beta, so all things arent promised to be working.  I took a look at react-native-tvos's readme and from what I can tell, all it does is provide remote support, provide functions for determining if the os a tv, and handles making buttons work as easily as they do on mobile. So if you can't wait for sdk 50 to leave beta, you could try to create the project as if it was for mobile and then recreate the tvos functionality as you need it

Comment: Well spotted brother, didn't pay attention to the expo version as I created the project from a template expo provides on their repo! thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was only with Expo Go, uninstall it from Android and download it again.